# Error loading library in mac terminal

Tags: terminal, dyld

Anyone please help..
How can I fix the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgdbm.4.dylib  
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/zsh  
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: You should probably provide more context as to what you were doing/running, otherwise folks won't be able to help you.

Comment: For me, this was the reason `tmux` was exiting with immediately with `[exited]`. Fixed with `brew upgrade zsh`.

Answer (score 121):

Simple reinstall zsh will help you:

```
brew reinstall zsh && brew unlink zsh && brew link zsh
```

Alternatively you can try to upgrade zsh

```
brew upgrade zsh
```

Comment: @AdamChubbuck for me it didn't help so I've just reinstalled it.

Comment: For those unable to open unable to even open a terminal window: @coderuby answer + comments  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52791702/4010391

Answer (score 42):

Late to the party on this one, but simply running

`brew upgrade zsh`

solved my issue on MacOS High Sierra. Trying to uninstall `gdbm` will throw dependency errors against `zsh` and `python`, and re-doing the symlinks didn't solve for me, either

Comment: This worked for me on after update to High Sierra 10.13.6. Thanks!

Comment: Now that you mention it, that's when mine broke as well. I pulled my disk image from a macbook running Sierra onto one with High Sierra and that's when problems arose

Comment: Worked for me too. I'd recommend trying this before reinstalling simply because it's faster

Comment: after trying quite a few (!) alternate approaches (incl. forced removal of gdbm and reinstallation) this worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you run the command? I can't open neither iTerm nor Terminal

Comment: @Gavriel I ran it in iTerm2. Usually the dependency should just block your zsh shell from running, not standard bash. What error does your terminal throw?

Answer (score 8):

I suspect you are running into problems while working with Homebrew on MacOSX. I am actually saying this because I have just run into the exact same situation.

The problem comes after upgrading my MacOSX version to Maverick from Mountain Lion while having already installed Homebrew (of course this may apply to previous and future upgrades). After the upgrade you will need also:

- Reinstall the XCode tools
- Run an update on Homebrew

  brew update
- Run a general upgrade of your Homebrew packages

  brew upgrade
- Make sure you do not have any other problems on your installation

  brew doctor

Finally you may find that certain packages are failing due to missing libraries, which seems to be the case you are describing. The idea here is to reinstall the library missing using the *brew* command.

In your case you would need to reinstall the **gdbm** library by performing the next steps on your terminal:

```
brew uninstall gdbm
brew install gdbm
```

That should fix it.

Answer (score 8):

To be able to fix my terminal/iterm2/hyper (all were broke because of broken zsh) I had to first change my terminal settings 'Shells open with' from a custom command to the default login shell.

[image]

Without these changes, I could not type anything in terminal and iterm2 and hyper were crashing immediately after start.

With these changes, I was able to update my zsh via homebrew as suggested in the other answers by De_Vano and C.Nivs and all three apps worked as expected again. In my case a simple upgrade of zsh was enough. No need to reinstall and unlink.

Comment: I have to switch to use /bin/bash first to use the terminal. Fix the problem as mentioned here, and change back to zsh

Answer (score 3):

After searching for a long time, this solved it for me:

```
brew reinstall ncurses
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and did not have an option to change the terminal on startup.

I ended up doing the following steps to resolve the problem:

1. Create a new user on my mac & enable remote login for him.
2. Login with the new user, which got a new working shell.
3. Changing the shell of my original account back to bash, using the chsh command.
4. Upgrading zsh using brew.

It Worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you facing the issue in iTerm2.
 You can simply change the path of your shell. Just go to `iTerm2>>Preferences>>profile>>General>>command`

Click on the dropdown and select `Command` and enter the command

`/bin/zsh`

**This worked for me**

Answer (score 0):

execute this command

```
   chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is raised from "ncurses"

If you are using OSX without any system manager like Conda, try:

```
brew reinstall ncurses
```

If you are using Conda, activate your environment and try this:

```
conda install -y conda-forge::ncurses
```

Goodluck