# Terminal crashes on start. How to get it back up?

Tags: zsh, dyld

I get this error when starting both iterm and terminal:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgdbm.4.dylib  
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/zsh  
  Reason: image not found
```

As far as I am tell I am unable to enter any commands into the terminal windows.

I found this thread where someone is getting the same error and is advised to reinstall zsh:

[Error loading library in mac terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103888/error-loading-library-in-mac-terminal)

That might work for me to. But where can I execute that?

Another alternative might be if it is possible to switch back to bash.

Comment: what does `ls -l /usr/local/lib/libgdbm.4.dylib` give you?

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [unix.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. More information is available in the [help].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In iTerm, select `Profiles>Open Profile>Default>General>Command>chsh -s /bin/bash`

Open a new shell window. Bash will be selected as the default shell.

Change the setting again `Profiles>Open Profile>Default>General>Command>Login shell`

Now the terminal will work again.

Comment: While inventive, I would suggest to first set `/bin/bash` as "Command", open a new window and then run `chsh -s /bin/bash` from there. This allows for more flexibility should any problems with `chsh` arise and you also will know if `/bin/bash` works, before setting it as login shell.

Comment: Given that the terminal emulator itself isn't started from any login shell, I would recommend not messing with `chsh` at all, and just configure iTerm to start whatever shell you want when you open a new window.

Comment: This was a life saver for me, thank you :)

Comment: Thank you! Life saver!!!

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. zsh asking for libgdbm.5.dylib, but I did not manage to start terminal by any of the answers I found. So, I went searching for the .dylib, and found ...6.dylib.
Here´s what I did, and it worked fine!

Find /..../libgdbm.?.glib.dylib, then copy/past the file. After pasting, rename it to the file, with the number requested. ie. "libgdbm.5.dylib